# Problems updating the DOM with sync XMLHttprequests

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Good lockdown Monday everyone.

I've been working on a solution for uploading large files to dropbox in chunks. All is going well so far. The below code relates to the sending of each chunk of the file.

The request is being sent synchronously so that the next chunk won't be sent until the current one has finished.

What I'm trying to do is update the width of a progress bar after each request is finished. However the whole browser screen freezes up (i assume because of the synchronous request) until the whole loop has finished and doesn't allow me to update the DOM at the end of each iteration.

Any suggestions?

```
jQuery(file.chunks).each(function(index, chunk){

    //First chunk has to go to a specific URL
    if (index == 0) {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        xhr.open('POST', 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload_session/start', false); 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer anaccesstoken');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Dropbox-API-Arg', JSON.stringify({close:false}));                 

    }

    //Remaining chunks go to a different URL
    if (index > 0) {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        xhr.open('POST', 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload_session/append_v2', false); 
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer anaccesstoken');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Dropbox-API-Arg', JSON.stringify({close:false}));                 

    }

    //Send the request
    xhr.send(chunk);

    //When sent, figure out the percentage uploaded and update the progress bar
    var percentage = 100 / dropbox.chunks.length * (index + 1);
    jQuery('.progress-bar').css('width',percentage+'%');

})
```

Comment: You are making synchronous ajax requests, I updated the question to say that

Comment: Why won't asynchronous work for you?

Comment: @Viney because the async doesnt wait for the request to complete before sending the next chunk for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest doing some "FAKE synchronous" using setTimeout as timers don't block main thread so you can update your views without any trouble

So here idea is to use mutex and timers to process individual items of an array one by one and mark them so as they get processed

Follow below snippet to get an idea and how you can use it in your case

```js
/* --------- fake data for stack snippet ----------*/
var file = {};
file.chunks = [

  'Francesco Bontempi',
  'Robbert van de Corput',
  'Tijs Michiel Verwest',
  'Elizabeth Woolridge Grant',
  'Stacy Ann Ferguson',
  'Alicia Augello Cook',
  'Joel Thomas Zimmerman',
  'Peter Gene Hernandez',
  'Madonna Louise Veronica Ciccone',

]
/* --------- ********************** ----------*/


var busy = false; //acts like a 'mutex' so we have only one upload in progress at any given time
var arr = []; // bucket in which we copy the file chunks to mark them later on (isComplete)
var timer = 0;

jQuery(file.chunks).each(function(index, chunk) {
  arr.push({
    item: chunk,
    isComplete: false
  });
  //here isComplete will help us track progress of each chunk
})

//@helper that will filter out uploaded items[ie. isComplete = true], 
//giving us the next item's index that is to be uploaded
function currentArrIndex() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].isComplete)
      continue
    else
      return i
  }
}


function process() {

  if (busy) {
    //we might hit here if a file takes longer than the current setTimeout interval (1sec)
    timer = setTimeout(process, 1000); //re-queue timer
  } else {

    if (currentArrIndex() < arr.length) {
      let xhrIndex = currentArrIndex()
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'http://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload_session/append_v2', true); //NOTE: true
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer anaccesstoken');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Dropbox-API-Arg', JSON.stringify({
        close: false
      }));

      xhr.onloadend = function() {
        arr[xhrIndex].isComplete = true;
        busy = false;
      }
      // So when ajax completes we'd mark this item as done and turn off busy 
      // so next item of arr will get processed in timer's next 'alarm'

      busy = true; // mark it as busy
      //And Send the request
      xhr.send(arr[xhrIndex].item);

      timer = setTimeout(process, 1000); //re-queue timer
    } else {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      alert('all chunks uploaded');
    }
  }

  //When sent, figure out the percentage uploaded and update the progress bar
  var percentage = 100 / arr.length * (currentArrIndex() + 1);
  jQuery('.progress-bar').css('width', percentage + '%');

}


function start() {
  alert('starting uploads');
  timer = setTimeout(process, 1000);
}
```

```css
#progress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>

<button onclick="start()">start</button>
```